# Integrate Millennial Media Ads in a Swift app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, millennial-media

I am currently developing an iOS app in Swift 2.0 and decided to use Millennial Media for their Ads. All their documentation refers to Objective-C codes and, although it's not much code at all, I cannot figure out how to port them over Swift.

I tried to search on StackOverflow and on Google but couldn't find anything at all.

I am trying to port the following:

- [Integration](http://docs.millennialmedia.com/ios-ad-sdk/integration-guide.html)
- [Inline Ads](http://docs.millennialmedia.com/ios-ad-sdk/inline-ads.html)
- [Interstitial Ads](http://docs.millennialmedia.com/ios-ad-sdk/interstitial-ads.html)

Thank you.

Comment: Could you find any solutions @luca-de-angelis?

Comment: Hi @Bernat, yes, see my answer below. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by integrating the [Google AdMob mediation adapter](http://docs.millennialmedia.com/android-ad-sdk/mediation-admob-to-millennial.html). Once integrated, everything is easily managed via the Google backend.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me in Swift.

Make sure you have the following in your bridging header:

```
#import <MMAdSDK/MMAdSDK.h>
```

Make sure to include the delegate in your class header:

```
class MyClass : UIViewController, MMInterstitialDelegate {
```

Declare your ad as a var:

```
var interstitialAd = MMInterstitialAd(placementId: "123456")
```

Call the following inside your viewDidLoad() method:

```
   interstitialAd?.delegate = self
   interstitialAd?.load(nil)
```

Use the following to display the Ad:

```
if ((interstitialAd?.ready) != nil) {
    interstitialAd?.showFromViewController(self)
}
```